# Tensorflow. Nonlinear regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, non-linear-regression

I have these feature and label, that are not linear enough to be satisfied with linear solution. I trained SVR(kernel='rbf') model from sklearn, but now its time to do it with tensorflow, and its hard to say what one should write to achieve same or better effect.

[image]

Do you see that lazy orange line down there? It doesn't fill you with determination

code itself:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from omnicomm_data.test_data import get_model, clean_df
import os
from sklearn import preprocessing

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# tf variables
x_ = tf.placeholder(name="input", shape=[None, 1], dtype=np.float32)
y_ = tf.placeholder(name="output", shape=[None, 1], dtype=np.float32)
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]), name='bias')
lin_model = tf.add(tf.multiply(x_, w), b)

#loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(lin_model - y_, 2), name='loss')
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.000000025).minimize(loss)

#nonlinear part
nonlin_model = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.multiply(x_, w), b))
nonlin_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(nonlin_model - y_, 2), name='cost')
train_step_nonlin = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.000000025).minimize(nonlin_loss)       


# pandas data
df_train = pd.read_csv('me_rate.csv', header=None)

liters = df_train.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
parrots = df_train.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)

#model for prediction
mms = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
rbf = get_model(path_to_model)


n_epochs = 200
train_errors = []
non_train_errors = []
test_errors = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(n_epochs)):

        _, train_err, summ = sess.run([train_step, loss, summaries],
                                feed_dict={x_: parrots, y_: liters})
        summary_writer.add_summary(summ, i)
        train_errors.append(train_err)

        _, non_train_err, = sess.run([train_step_nonlin, nonlin_loss],
                                      feed_dict={x_: parrots, y_: liters})
        non_train_errors.append(non_train_err)


    plt.plot(list(range(n_epochs)), train_errors, label='train_lin')
    plt.plot(list(range(n_epochs)), non_train_errors, label='train_nonlin')
    plt.legend()
    print(train_errors[:10])
    print(non_train_errors[:10])
    plt.show()

    plt.scatter(parrots, liters, label='actual data')
    plt.plot(parrots, sess.run(lin_model, feed_dict={x_: parrots}), label='linear (tf)')
    plt.plot(parrots, sess.run(nonlin_model, feed_dict={x_: parrots}), label='nonlinear (tf)')
    plt.plot(parrots, rbf.predict(mms.fit_transform(parrots)), label='rbf (sklearn)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

## How to motivate that orange line?

Part After.

Code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from omnicomm_data.test_data import get_model
import os
from sklearn import preprocessing

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# tf variables
x_ = tf.placeholder(name="input", shape=[None, 1], dtype=np.float32)
y_ = tf.placeholder(name="output", shape=[None, 1], dtype=np.float32)
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([]), name='bias')

# nonlinear
nonlin_model = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.tanh(x_), w), b)
nonlin_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(nonlin_model - y_, 2), name='cost')
train_step_nonlin = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(nonlin_loss)


# pandas data
df_train = pd.read_csv('me_rate.csv', header=None)


liters = df_train.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
parrots = df_train.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)


#model for prediction
mms = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
rbf = get_model(path_to_model)


nz = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler()  # normalization coz tanh
norm_parrots = nz.fit_transform(parrots)
print(norm_parrots)

n_epochs = 20000
train_errors = []
non_train_errors = []
test_errors = []
weights = []
biases = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(n_epochs)):

        _, non_train_err, weight, bias = sess.run([train_step_nonlin, nonlin_loss, w, b],
                                      feed_dict={x_: norm_parrots, y_: liters})
        non_train_errors.append(non_train_err)
        weights.append(weight)
        biases.append(bias)


    plt.scatter(norm_parrots, liters, label='actual data')

    plt.plot(norm_parrots, sess.run(nonlin_model, feed_dict={x_: norm_parrots}), c='orange', label='nonlinear (tf)')
    plt.plot(norm_parrots, rbf.predict(mms.fit_transform(parrots)), label='rbf (sklearn)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]
Asyoucanclearlysee we got some improvements for orange line (not quite good as rbf, but its just need more work).

Comment: This is very good! But you should put the answer in an actual answer to the question to keep with SO structure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `tf.tanh` as activation, it means that your output is limited in the range [-1,1]. Therefore it will never fit your data.

Edit: I have removed a part noticing a typo that has already been fixed.

Comment: yeah, I've fixed it after I copied a code, but forgot to fix it here, thank you for noticing. Sadly it didn't help to orange line...

Comment: @GrailFInder with the `tanh` function it will never work.